# Calling Code Behind Method From Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using `Asp.net/C#` in my project , i have a requirement where in the user enters a name and the details of that person is displayed `asp.net gridview` ,,,, i am planning to use `html button` instead of `asp.net button` because the results displayed will be in  tab...However the function which will populate the `gridview` is in `code behind` ,, so my question is how will i call that method from `jquery`,,, is that possible.Or is there any better way of doing this......
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have look to this post which describe you how to call function of code behind : [Calling Server Side function from Client Side Script](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2012/01/calling-server-side-function-from.html)

**Cs File (codebehind)**

```
[WebMethod] 
public static string IsExists(string value) 
{     
    //code to check uniqe value call to database to check this     
   return "True";
 }
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
function IsExists(pagePath, dataString)
 {
  $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url: pagePath,
     data: dataString,
     contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType:"json",
     error:
          function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {               
               alert("Error");
          },
     success:
          function(result) {
                  alert( result.d);

      }
     }
});}

      var pagePath = window.location.pathname + "/IsExists";
     var dataString = "{ 'value':'ab" }";
     IsExists(pagePath, dataString);
```